# High rate of InternalServerError from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So according to Amazon's DynamoDB [error handling docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html), it's expected behavior that you might receive 500 errors sometimes (they do not specify why this might occur or how often). In such a case, you're suppose to implement retries with exponential backoff, starting about 50ms.

In my case, I'm processing and batch writing a very large amount of data in parallel (30 nodes, each running about 5 concurrent threads). I expect this to take a very long time.

My hash key is fairly well balanced (user_id) and my throughput is set to 20000 write capacity units.

When I spin things up, all starts off pretty well. I hit the throughput and start backing off and for a while I oscillate nicely around the max capacity. However, pretty soon I start getting tons of 500 responses with InternalServerError as the exception. No other information is provided, of course. I back off and I back off, until I'm waiting about 1 minute between retries and everything seizes up and I'm no longer getting 200s at all.

I feel like there must be something wrong with my queries, or perhaps specific queries, but I have no way to investigate. There's simply no information about my error coming back from the server beyond the "Internal" and "Error" part.

Halp?

Comment: It seems I may have spoken too soon. If I wait some time, the errors reduce. I suppose under constant load the quality of the responses can be quite variable.

Comment: do you have any LSIs declared? It's my understanding that additional indexes require additional write capacity.

Comment: Thanks @andreimarinescu, yes I do have one secondary index, but I'm accounting for it in my throughput capacity. I don't believe the throughput is the issue though. I am backing off automatically when I receive throttling errors. The problem is that I start getting nothing but the very generic "InternalServerError" response. [Here's a typical pattern that I see.](http://f.cl.ly/items/3f2A1P470m2M3B2i3z2Y/Image%202013.11.23%208%3A30%3A48%20AM.png)

Comment: InternalServerError from any AWS API means something is wrong on the AWS side. I would suggest contacting AWS directly.

Comment: Thanks @prestomation, I did contact them and yes, it was something they could fix. Although I never did get a proper explanation...